# Импорт константы из js файла

Tags: javascript

**Есть константа которую нужно импортировать в main.js из файла text.js**

Файл text.js

```
export const registerTexts = {
    "home_page-title": {
        ru: "Регистрация",
        en: "Registration",
    },
    "home_page-0": {
        ru: "Регистрация",
        en: "Registration",
    },
    "home_page-1": {
        ru: "Почта",
        en: "Email",
    },
    "home_page-2": {
        ru: "Пароль",
        en: "Password",
    },
    "home_page-3": {
        ru: "Повторите пароль",
        en: "Repeat password",
    },
    "home_page-4": {
        ru: "Имя пользователя",
        en: "Username",
    },
    "home_page-5": {
        ru: "Зарегистрироваться",
        en: "Register",
    },
};
```

Файл main.js

`import {registerTexts} from "./text.js"`

Но константу не получается использовать. Я только начинаю изучать js, кто сможет помочь понять в чем проблема заранее спасибо)

Comment: Как она используется? И есть ли какие ошибки?

Comment: Используется она для мультиязычности сайта, если я попытаюсь вывести ее в консоль для проверки что все работает то выдает ошибку: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. import call expects one or two arguments.

Comment: Import/export в браузере просто так работать не будет. Нужен сборщик.

Comment: Если это HTML, должен быть установлен `<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>`

Comment: А что это такое?

Comment: А куда вставлять ""type="module""

Comment: Прямо в тег скрипта, я дописал.

Comment: Выдает ошибку: SyntaxError: Cannot declare a const variable twice: 'registerTexts'.

Comment: А нет заработал,  спасибо)